# Nginx - rewrite $request_uri to use in limit_req_zone

Tags: nginx

Есть Nginx, который принимает запросы:

```
http://example.com:8181/test
http://example.com:8181/test?var=varq&var2=warw
```

Конфиг файл который ограничивает количество запросов 30 в минуту

```
    limit_req_zone $request_uri zone=lim_30_min:16m rate=30r/m;


server {
    listen       8181;
    server_name  test;
    root /opt/test/;
    location /test {
    limit_req zone=lim_30_min;
    limit_req_status 429;
    }
```

Проблема в том что передавая запросы в параметрах которых будут новые значения - лимитирование не будет работать.

Как переназначить $request_uri обрезав до знака "?" ?

Comment: Использовать `$uri`

Answer (score 0):

Да, спасибо. Использование `$uri` вместо `$request_uri` как раз дал результат.